# How do I post the value of multiple answered checkboxes? - PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following code below that retrieves one of four optional checkbox answers to one quesition.

In my database instead of reading the correpsonding value, it always posts `0`for each time a box is ticked. I'm guessing this is the key. How is it possible to show the value here?  I tried replacing key with value, but with no success.

**-Here are my codes-**

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['Person'] as $key=>$Person) { 
    $_POST['Person'][$key] = intval($Person); 
}
$Person = implode(',', $_POST['Person']);
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="ratings">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[1]" value="Excellent" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[2]" value="Good" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[3]" value="Satisfactory" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[4]" value="Poor" /></li>                    
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't postin `On` and not `0`?

Comment: What do you think `intval("Excellent")` returns?

Comment: Shouldn't these be radio buttons, not checkboxes, so you can only select one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Person = implode(',', array_keys($_POST['Person']));
```

In the `_POST['Person']` array, the keys are `1, 2, 3, 4`, the values are `Excellent, Good, Satisfactory, Poor`. In your code, you were calling `intval()` on the values, which returns `0` for anything that isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['Person'][$key] = intval($Person);
```

This statement will take the intval of the checkboxes which is currently "Satisfactory". So yes the intval of a string is 0.

Look at this script:

```
<form action="test.php" name="checkbox" method="post">
    <ul class="ratings">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[1]" value="Excellent"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[2]" value="Good"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[3]" value="Satisfactory"/></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="Person[4]" value="Poor"/></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<pre>
<?php

print_r($_POST);

echo "intval of " . intval($_POST[0]); // Converts the string to the value 0 ALWAYS


?>
</pre>
```

Output (Notice the `$key` is the integer and the value is the string)

```
Array
(
    [Person] => Array
        (
            [3] => Satisfactory
            [4] => Poor
        )

)
intval of 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I asked the quesition correctly but once i researched similar functions to intval, I replaced it with strval to display the value i needed in the database.

```
$_POST['Person'][$key] = strval($Person);
```